# Junks ax after expression

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, intel-syntax

This code works as a **IN func for i/o ports** in inline c:

```
int func(short port)
{
    short data;
    __asm__(
        ".intel_syntax \n\t"
        "in byte %0, %1\n\t"

        ".att_syntax\n\t"
        :"=a" (data)
        :"dN" (port)
        :
    );
    return data;
}
```

but on compiling the c code the assembler outputs:

```
file.c:5: Error: junk `ax' after expression
```

Here is the compiling command

> gcc -ffreestanding -m32 -c file.c -o file.o

I tried viewing the code in assemly using **-S** flag but it seems to be fine

Comment: You forgot the `noprefix` part of `.intel_syntax noprefix`.  Also, what is `byte` doing there?    That's not how GAS Intel syntax works, and it doesn't match the size of the register GCC will pick for a `short`.  `byte` is the expression after which GAS found another token, not a comma, thus junk.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes I changed the code as you mentioned and it fixed the error

Comment: BTW, using Intel syntax with GCC inline asm is cumbersome ([Can I use Intel syntax of x86 assembly with GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9347909)), and that's not a great way to do it.  It will break if you ever compile with `-masm=intel`, since it puts the assembler into AT&T mode for the rest of the file.  Avoiding that requires dialect-alternatives like `in{b %1, %0 | %0, %1}` (which picks one side of the `{att | intel}`)

Comment: Better to just use AT&T syntax for simple stuff, so you can write `inb` to force the assembler to check for a byte register instead of relying on the register to imply the IO width.  [seg fault on IN instruction, inline assembly GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48178058) shows one way to write a correct AT&T wrapper. (The bug there is trying to use it in user-space.)

Comment: Hmm, with the mutant hybrid `.intel_syntax prefix` you used, that asks for register names like `%al` or `%ax` you're getting from GCC, despite being in Intel syntax mode for operand-order.  But GAS is ok either way, and clang only accepts the two sane options: `.intel_syntax noprefix` or `.att_syntax [prefix]`.